# pip3 packages are getting installed in /home/user/.local/python3.8/site-packages/ but not able to use them at all

Tags: package-management, 20.04, python, pip

I am using ubuntu 20.04, as and when I install any package using

```
pip3 install any_python_pacakage
```

everything gets installed and there occurs no problem.

But when I try to use to any package using:

```
from any_package_name import any_name
```

I am getting the following error:

*ImportError: cannot import name 'build' from 'googleapiclient.discovery' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py)*

Please help, because I cannot use any package installed using pip3.

Any help needed from my side, I am ready.

All files installed with 0 size

[image: All files installed with 0 size]

After doing `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>`

new error is as:

[image]

Comment: did you try `sudo -H pip3 install PackageName` ?

Comment: And I am adding a new image in the question, and there you can see that every file is of zero size

Comment: Did this just now, but now the package got installed into /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages and now I tried running the script and the new error is :

`ImportError: cannot import name 'build' from 'googleapiclient.discovery' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py)`

Answer (score 0):

First try to force reinstall the package. I am unsure why every file is empty but something must have gone wrong when you first installed the package. An empty file would explain the import error message you are seeing.

`pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>`

I would not recommend invoking pip with sudo as this can modify your system's Python packages which in general should only be manged by your system package manager (e.g. apt-get, yum, etc.). Modifying system Python packages has the potential to break other system components that depend on them.

Comment: I did so but now, I encountered new and very strange errors, I am adding it to the question.

Comment: Same type of error, but now it's complaining about the requests Python package. I suspect that package also has empty files on your system. Do the same force reinstall for `requests` package as well. Whatever happened to cause all of these empty files it is likely also affecting many more installed packages.

Comment: What I can see right now is, every file under /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/any_pkg_folder is empty,
and I don't know what is messing it up all?

Comment: and now doing any pip3 installation is not working at all, even the command you told earlier is not working at all, as I was trying to force reinstall the `requests` pkg

And the error is the same as I have posted in 2nd image of the question

Comment: It might be faster just to delete or rename the ` /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` folder to something else, and then start at the beginning and install the Python packages you need. Something went very wrong with your local user Python packages.

Comment: I don't know what happened wrong, because I didn't do any config changes ever for pip3/python3.8, but please help, if You can refer someone who can resolve, that'll be appreciable and helpful, coz I am stuck here since 2 weeks and I am not ablle to do anything